# Javascript: two buttons set two timestamp

Tags: javascript, forms, text, input, timestamp

I have a form, with two text input (two timestamp) as follows:

TimeStamp start []
TimeStamp end []

Both TimeStamps are to be filled automatically with two buttons:
[Set Start] and [Set End], that read the local timestamp in the form (24h):

2013-06-27 23:55

TimeStamp start is when the operator start filling the form, while
TimeStamp end is when the form ends to be filled (the delay between these events can be also of 1 hour)

The data are then processed by POST to a script PHP

How I can handle this timestamp settings on the client side (JS, JQuery?)

Thanks in advance

@manraj82

I found this JS function to get timestamp with JS

```
function getTimeStamp() { 
    var now = new Date(); 
    return ((now.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + (now.getDate()) + '/' + now.getFullYear() + "   
    " + now.getHours() + ':' + ((now.getMinutes() < 10) ? ("0" + now.getMinutes()) :  
    (now.getMinutes())) + ':' + ((now.getSeconds() < 10) ? ("0" + now.getSeconds()) : 
    (now.getSeconds()))); 
 }
```

Now I have to associate it to two buttons

Comment: Have you got any code that you have tried?

Comment: I found the above js function to get timestamp:

Answer (score 0):

I didnt quite undesrtand what your question was but try this.This might not be the answer but will give you an idea

```
Date.prototype.addHours= function(h){
    var newDateTime = new Date(this);

    newDateTime.setHours(newDateTime.getHours() + h);
    return newDateTime;
}

function getTimeStamp(dt) { 
    return (
    (dt.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + 
    (dt.getDate()) + '/' + dt.getFullYear() +
    " " + 
     dt.getHours() + ':' + 
    ((dt.getMinutes() < 10) ? ("0" + dt.getMinutes()) : (dt.getMinutes())) + ':' + 
    ((dt.getSeconds() < 10) ? ("0" + dt.getSeconds()) : (dt.getSeconds()))); 
 }


var startDateTime = new Date(),
    addHours = 10,
    endDateTime = startDateTime.addHours(addHours);

console.log(getTimeStamp(startDateTime));
console.log(getTimeStamp(endDateTime));
```